# Returning multiple JSON from php to android using volley

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I have two tables

```
UserName  Name
user01    name01
user02    name02
```

**my second table**

```
Name      Subject
name01    math
name01    english
```

**My php:**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

      $id  = $_GET['UserName'];
    require_once('connect.php');

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE UserName='".$id."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'UserName'=>$row[0],
        'name'=>$row[1],

        )
    );
       $sqll= "SELECT * FROM subjecttable WHERE UserName='".$id."'";
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    }

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

}

echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

now I have to receive the json inside while loop as well as the json outside the loop… right now I can receive the json outside while loop

**my android code for retrieving the json outside the while loop**

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
    for (int x = 0; x < result.length(); x++) {
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
        username = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_UserName);
        name = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_NAME);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Inside that while loop it will return the subjects in my second table and I should retrieve all of them…

Comment: Your PHP should not echo the JSON inside the while loop

Comment: "Returning multiple JSON from php" -- Use two different URLs

Comment: But that wont meet my requirements,i need the query inside while loop as my tables are dependent on each other

Comment: It would seem you need a SQL JOIN statement on the `name` column...

Comment: Can you show it with an example?

Comment: `select a.Username, a.Name, b.Subject as Subject from table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.Name = b.Name`

Comment: It's not really clear what your expected JSON output is...

Comment: The json outside while loop returns the name,(it will fetch the name via username column )
and the json inside will return the subjects

Comment: Well, Volley is expecting a single JSON object or array, as shown by `new JSONObject(response);`. It cannot parse any more than that. If you have multiple lines of JSON being written by PHP, then you need to parse them as Strings line-by-line. But that is pointless when you could re-write the PHP code to combine the results into a single JSON object

Comment: Please [edit] your question. 1) Show more of your PHP code. What is `queryresult` or `$r`? 2) Show the JSON you are trying to parse. 3) In order to make a [mcve], you need to hard-code those `config` constant key variables in the Java code.

Comment: Can you show me implementation in php ...with which i can combine the json returning subject and json returning the name(outside while loop)

Comment: I will try once you show what format you are trying to write the JSON as.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend something like `[ {"username": "user01", "name": "name01", "subjects": ["math", "english"] }, ]`, but like I said, that requires a JOIN statement on the two tables

Comment: I dont know how to implement JOIN statement

Comment: Well, prime opportunity to take some time to play around with SQL and learn. Your immediate problem seems to not be the JSON but how to "find all subjects for all students".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I did receive the multiple jsons but combining them both

```
    {
"result":[
{"date":"01-01-2016",
"day_name":"Friday"},{"date":"02-01-2016",
"day_name":"Saturday"},{"date":"03-01-2016",
"day_name":"Sunday"},{"date":"04-01-2016",
"day_name":"Monday"},{"date":"05-01-2016",
"day_name":"Tuesday"},{"date":"06-01-2016",
"day_name":"Wednesday"},{"date":"07-01-2016",
"day_name":"Thursday"},
{MY OTHER JSON EXAMPLE--->"monday":"9",
"tuesday":"9" }]}
```

Then i used two for loops inside onresponse

First for loop was 0 to result.length-1...That wont include the last array 
Then the second for was from result.length-1 to result.length.
With this implementation i was able to take different jsons when a single onResponse

**NOTE** The second json should not be a repeating set.

```
 private void showJSON(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
        for(int x=0;x<result.length()-1;x++) {

            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
            //collecting present object in json
            ClassList.add(new totalClassObject(collegeData.getString("date"),collegeData.getString("day_name")));
            RefreshListVIew();

        }
        for(int x=result.length()-1;x<result.length();x++) {

            JSONObject collegeDays = result.getJSONObject(x);
            //For Fetching Second type json
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```